# Плавная прокрутка экрана вверх

Tags: html, jquery, css

Нужна небольшая стрелочка в углу экрана для плавной прокрутки экрана в топ.
Есть html:

```
<p style="margin-left: 0px;" id="back-top"><a href="#top"><span></span></a></p>
```

Для него CSS:

```
#back-top{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
        left: 0px;
}

#back-top a{
    width:55px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    font:11px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    -moz-transition:1s;
    transition:1s;
}
#back-top span{
    width:45px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:7px;
        background: url('../img/up-arrow.png') no-repeat bottom center;
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    -moz-transition:1s;
    transition:1s;
}

#back-top a:hover span{background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
```

Использую jquery 1.11.3.min:

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $(function (){
        $("#back-top").hide();

        $(window).scroll(function (){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 700){
                $("#back-top").fadeIn();
            } else{
                $("#back-top").fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $("#back-top a").click(function (){
            $("body,html").animate({
                scrollTop:0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

рабоает в IE, но прокручивает не плавно.. В Google и Mozila не исчезает, а блок виден всегда+прокрутка не плавная.
в jquery поигрался со скоростью и длиной прокрутки , но не пашет все равно как нужно...
В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед в интернете полно уже готовых скриптов прокрутки страницы вверх.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут работает?

У вас две ошибки в первых двух строчках

`(document).ready(function(){` без `$` и еще одно `$(function (){`, которое является синонимом первой строки, то есть вы два раза одно и тоже вызываете.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#back-top").hide();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 700) {
      $("#back-top").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $("#back-top").fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $("#back-top a").click(function() {
    $("body,html").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
#back-top {
  position: fixed
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:2000px">
  <div id="back-top"><a href="#">Наверх</a>
  </div>
</div>
```